# Email settings configuration in Sonar not working

Tags: sonarqube

I have configured the email settings for my `Sonar` instance under `Configuration--> general Seetings --> Email` .

The configuration details are as below.

```
SMTP host: mysmtpserver.com<br>
SMTP Port: 25<br>
Use secure connection: No<br>
SMTP username: Blank<br>
SMTP password:Blank<br>
From address:noreply@mycompany.sonar.com<br>
Email prefix: [SONAR]
```

I have saved these settings and when I try to test it, I get the below error in Sonar screen

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mysmtpserver.com:25
```

Below is the stracktrace of the exception

```
2012.06.12 12:10:11 ERROR o.s.p.e.EmailNotificationChannel  Fail to send test email to: myname@mycompany.com
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mysmtpserver.com:25
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.emailnotifications.EmailNotificationChannel.send(EmailNotificationChannel.java:192) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.emailnotifications.EmailNotificationChannel.sendTestEmail(EmailNotificationChannel.java:210) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:559) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:404) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:79) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:205) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallThreeArgNode.interpret(CallThreeArgNode.java:61) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:103) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:216) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:120) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83) [jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar:na]
```

Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 anonymous client does not have permissions to send as this sender (by tpa)

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1515) ~[na:na]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1321) ~[na:na]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:637) ~[na:na]
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189) ~[na:na]
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232) ~[na:na]
... 248 common frames omitted
```

Note: The same SMTP server settings work fine for `Gerrit` and `Jenkins` without requiring any authentication.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your SMTP server does not allow sending mails anonymously (i.e. without a user & a password) when you provide a "from address".

You should take a look at the configuration of your Jenkins or Gerrit instances, they probably do not specify any "from address". In that case, remove the "noreply@mycompany.sonar.com" entry and make a try.

Comment: Jenkins does allow to configure the "Sender E-Mail Address" which we have configured and email sending from Jenkins work fine with the same SMTP server and without requiring any authentication. The only difference is that it does not mandate to enter the port number of the SMTP server. However, I gave a try to remove the from address and now it gives me a different exception i.e. org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Illegal address . I can confirm for sure that the email address provided to test the configuration is valid and correct