# Stuck while trying to send email notification from SonarQube

Tags: email, sonarqube

I could'n send email notification from sonarqube even after configuring the email server, from  `Settings > General Settings > General > Email`

I tried following  : [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995912/email-settings-configuration-in-sonar-not-working) but I got the same message error : `Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587`

Have I to set up something out of SonarQube ?

Answer (score 3):

To send email through GMail SMTP server, you should use the following configuration:

- SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
- SMTP Port: 465
- Use secure connection: SSL/TLS

Obviously, you have to specify your username ("foo.bar@gmail.com") and a password (generated in your GMail security settings).

Comment: Thank you Fabrice for your reply, I tried this but it doesn't work, there are other fields : **SMTP username** & **SMTP password** &  **From address**  have I to let them empty ?

Comment: Yes, you have to specify those fields.

Comment: I specified **SMTP username** by my email, **SMTP password** by following this article to generate the password :  [link](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-generate-google-app-specific-password-2-step-verification.html) , and **From address** field by my email ... but still get the same message error...any suggestions ?

Comment: Port should be 587

Comment: Correct, what @Santosh b said is right, this should be updated with `starttls` secure connection type with `smtp.gmail.com` SMTP server with `587` SMTP port

Answer (score 0):

From your SonarQube instance go to:

```
Settings > General Settings > General > Email
```

Set:
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port: 587
Use secure connection: SSL/TLS

Fill in your smtp.username and smtp.password by generating an app password in gmail. This [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) might work.